# Allow users to select text in a webview android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a webview in my app that I would like to allow users to highlight text in yellow there.

I need to allow users to select, undo the select text and keep the selected text for next time user open the app. Any ideas how can I archive this in java?

I saw some other posts here, but they are old and using some basic javascript that not keep the results and do not allow user to undo the selected texts.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since it's webview, your loading a page; if the page is yours, and there's a user system of some sorts, why not attempt to do it on the actual web client (javascript, etc.) that's a part of the page rendered?

Comment: @IlanP thanks for your answer. Do you know any javascript plugin that I can add to my webviews and would work nice in mobile context?

Comment: If you take a look at some popular libraries for JQ, https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/ (check the demo on some of these scripts) they can easily be implemented on your web client and retain the functionality when loaded through your android UI; it's worth checking out.